# Unable to get dynos to start on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying deploy my app on Heroku. I am new to this btw. Atm i am not able to get `heroku ps:scale web=1` command to work. Failing with `Couldn't find that process type (web).`

I can confirm i have my Procfile ready with the following entry,

```
web: gunicorn pages_project.wsgi --log-file -
```

The error as per the log file is,

```
2018-12-05T10:19:11.205407+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"
```

I had no issues using git to sync between Bitbucket and Heroku. I could not find an option to add a dyno using the Heroku dashboard. I searched around and found this article on Medium [How to Deploy a Django App to Heroku in 2018](https://medium.com/@qazi/how-to-deploy-a-django-app-to-heroku-in-2018-the-easy-way-48a528d97f9c) but i still can't get it to work.

I am using a virtualenv and my project has the following components,

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==19.8.1
psycopg2==2.7.6.1
pytz==2018.7
whitenoise==4.1.2
```

Can someone help me on this ? Thank you.

Comment: What's the exact name of your Procfile? I think case matters, so `procfile` and `Procfile` are two different things. Also make sure it's not `Procfile.txt` or something like that. Finally, did you remember to push the Procfile? :)

Comment: And where is it in relation to the rest of your code?

Comment: @AndréLaszlo The name of the file is Procfile no extensions but when I do get info on my Mac it shows TextEdit Document under kind property. I created the file from VSCode. Yes I did push the Procfile and i can see it in Bitbucket.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Its on my pages_project directory. I am going through the directory structure to see if the Procfile should be somewhere else. Will get back to you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman so upon rechecking it looks like i put the Procfile where it shouldn't be. It was in an app folder wherein fact it should be in the project directory. Upon moving and going through the process of deploying to Heroku its working fine. Thank you for the helpful hint.